# Display textarea output as a list with bullets

Tags: php, html, css, textarea

I have a form with a `textarea` into which my clients write several phrases/sentences of which typically each one spans one or two lines, and they press the return key to insert a linebreak / begin the next phrase.

Ideally, when this text is fetched from the database and displayed on the webpage, it should have some kind of list format, i.e. a bullet or a `-` character at the beginning of each phrase.

So it should appear like a typical list with `ul` and `li`. But in a plain textarea field you can only do a new-line, no formating. I use `nl2br($mytext)` to convert these to new-line events to `<br>` tags in the output. But is there anything similar to convert the whole text into a list or list items (`li`)?

I know I could use TinyMCE and let them format it, but I don't want them to format anything, I *only*  want these separated lines displayed as a list.

I thought about adding `:before` pseudo elements containing bullets to the `br` tags, but those are the end of the lines, not at the beginning - won't work... Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: to the downvoters: what kind of code do you expect me to post? I can't simulate text content being first written into a form and later being fetched from a database in a snippet, codepen or jsfiddle...

Comment: So to boil your question down if I understand, you're looking for a way to take your carriage return separated database records and display them as a list? Is that correct?

Comment: @j08691 yes, that's basically it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string by new lines and implode it with `'<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $string) . '</li></ul>'`.

Comment: Ah, that's great! Thank you very much!