# How can I force a list of br-separated links to be shown as bulleted list?

Tags: html, css

I am using a process system which allows me to set up email templates. The template includes a variable/placeholder for a `<br>`-separated list of links, which I can't change.

Template mail body example:

```
<p>Here's your link list:</p>
{!LinkList}
```

which generates mail bodies like this:

```
<p>Here's your link list:</p>
<a href="link1">Link 1</a><br>
<a href="link2">Link 2</a><br>
<a href="link3">Link 3</a><br>
```

**I want to display all of these links as a bulleted list.** I can wrap `<ul>` tags around the `{!LinkList}` placeholder, but I can't force `<li>` tags inside it. Is there another way, e.g. by styling the `<a>` tags with `list-style-type` to show up with bullets?

I've tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
<p>Here's your link list:</p>
<ul style="list-style-type:bullet;">
{!LinkList}
</ul>
```

Comment: "Is there another way, e.g. by styling the <a> tags with list-style-type to show up with bullets?" Did you try doing just that?

Comment: If your list content comes as output in PHP format, this question and answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43747444/5641669

Comment: @HereticMonkey I tried it indirectly by styling the <ul> tags (see the last code snippet), which didn't work. I can't access the <a> tags directly, as they are hidden in the placeholder.

Comment: This is CSS, which need not, and indeed should not, be applied inline, so your access to the HTML is irrelevant. Use a stylesheet to apply the styling to the anchors. BTW, the only valid child elements of a `ul` are `li` elements, so you don't want that `ul` there anyway. Use a `div` with a `class`, or a `nav` if appropriate.